# How do you update the AudioUnit Instrument

Tags: macos, audiounit

When a user changes a parameter or preset, how/when do I actually update the instrument?

There's no `ParameterUpdated` or `PresetSelected` type of method/callback in `AUInstrumentBase`

Answer (score 0):

The relevant mechanism is the AUPreset struct in AudioUnitProperties.h.  kAudioUnitProperty_PresentPreset under AudioUnitSetProperty receives this.  See the old FilterDemo and TremoloUnit demo files from Apple to see this in action.

Comment: Could you explain `AudioUnitSetProperty`? I've looked through the docs but I'm still a bit confused. When I move the slider for a parameter, is this function called? Which argument for this function holds the id of the parameter that was changed?